# Open two popups

Tags: angularjs, html, angularjs-directive

How I can open two pop ($ mdDialog) one after another without closing either until I indicated, it is with angularjs, is there some property of $ mdDialog to do that? or How I can do?

Comment: you can refer this for your requirement https://github.com/angular/material/issues/698